# Restrict access to a directory to just one process and its children

Tags: sshfs, access-control

I want to mount a remote directory via `sshfs` to the local machine in order to use a code editor (Visual Studio Code) to locally edit files on the remote location.

Is there a way to limit access to that local mount to just the code editor? I don't want any other process to be able to access it as a safety measure, since those mounts will be up for hours, while the editor will likely be not. I'd start the editor and execute a command which fetches the process id of the editor and somehow magically applies the access restriction to the directory. This is wishful thinking, but what are my options? I'd consider using chroot (which I don't know if it could be the solution) as a last resort because I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Have you considered using visual studio code's [remote development](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack) extension? You wouldn't need to mount the code at all in this case, VS code would transparently work across SSH.

Comment: I have. The remote machine is run on a server in a VM. When the CPU load hits 100% (or high filesystem I/O?) for a time, filesystem corruption starts to occur. https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10031?cversion=0&cnum_hist=14 so I'm looking to upgrade the machine with the VM in it, but I want to have what is stated in the question as an alternative / workaround

Comment: But this bug is also not the only reason. I want to have other processes to access it, but have control over what accesses them. For example for a local git repository.